# ManyToMany bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities "page" and "category" and i want to make manytomany relation between them !

Here is my code below but i don't know why it doesn't worK !it has been 3 days that 'm trying but in vain...

```
class Category
{
    /**
 * @var Page
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SDIN\ChocoLinksPagesBundle\Entity\Page", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_page", schema = "tramegenerator",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Page_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $page;

class Page
{
    /**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Category[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SDIN\ChocoLinksPagesBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="page", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $categories;
```

Any help please !

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @kormik [3/3] TableNotFoundException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.title AS title_2, t0.content AS content_3, t0.colSize AS colsize_4, t0.type AS type_5, t0.list AS list_6 FROM tramegenerator.clp_category t0 INNER JOIN page_category ON t0.id = page_category.category_id WHERE page_category.page_id = ?' with params [2]:

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "page_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._6 FROM tramegenerator.clp_category t0 INNER JOIN page_categ...

Comment: did you update your schema ?  it seems your database is missing a table ..

Comment: Thank you for your comment that was usefull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is saying: `TableNotFoundException: An exception occurred while executing`

if you use redis clear the redis cache like this `redis-cli flushall`.

then run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to check the changes if all is ok run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

if you use symfony 2.8/3.0+ use `bin` instead of `app`